# Object detection android lib

Tags: android, opencv, automation, geometry

Hi is there any android library to detect real object , i want to detect bike wheel.

I have tried openCV examples but it doesn't work, i just want to detect two wheels of bike. letter on i want get wheels size, bike tube angle, height

here is some link of app :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mantapix.android.theroadiebikefit&hl=en

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.canouet.android.smb

i am using Android studio.

Comment: AFAIK, No openCV example has a wheel example. Can you post what example you're using?

Comment: @EdwardShen here is link https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/3.1.0/OpenCV-3.1.0-android-sdk.zip/download

Comment: i can show camera in this SDK but it's can't detect object as i want can you help me out ?

Comment: It looks like you just provided me with the SDK. Take a look at how to use the `train_cascade` program [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html). This will get you started.